# Androidのcheckboxのサイズをコードで変更したい

Tags: android

Androidで、checkbox のサイズをコードだけで指定する方法はありますか？

画像を使用する方法はよく見かけるのですが、コードだけでサイズを調整する方法が見当たらないのです…。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

基本的には、https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151241/android-how-to-change-checkbox-size
で回答されている内容をjavaにそのまま落とせば実現できます。
CheckboxもViewの種類なのでViewに定義されているメソッドは大体使えます。
[Android DevelopersのViewの説明](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)の
`XML Attributes`という項目にxml⇄javaの置換表が掲載されているので
一度ご参照になってはいかがでしょうか。
とりあえず、一番簡単そうだった

```
<CheckBox
    ...
    android:scaleX="0.70"
    android:scaleY="0.70"
/>
```

をjavaのソースコードで実現してみました。
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/checkbox.html
のソースコードを一部借りています。

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox_meat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="meat"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    CheckBox mCheckBoxMeat;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mCheckBoxMeat = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_meat);
        if (mCheckBoxMeat.isChecked()) {
            mCheckBoxMeat.setChecked(false);
        }
    }

    public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
        // Is the view now checked?
        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

        // Check which checkbox was clicked
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.checkbox_meat:
                if (checked) {
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    // 要らないかも。
                    layoutParams.gravity = RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT;
                    layoutParams.gravity = RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP;
                    mCheckBoxMeat.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    mCheckBoxMeat.setScaleX(0.7f);
                    mCheckBoxMeat.setScaleY(0.7f);

                } else {
                    // 何となくわざと。
                    view.setLayoutParams(
                            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    view.setScaleX(1.0f);
                    view.setScaleY(1.0f);
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

チェックがない(デフォルト時)
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

チェックを付けた時
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「xml⇄javaの置換表」に気づいてませんでした！ありがとうございます！！